# how to parse a json file via jackson?

Tags: json, javabeans, jackson

I am using Jackson to parse a JSON object.  It works perfectly but in bean class one of the member variables is dynamic.  This means sometimes my json attribute returns an array of strings and sometimes same attribute `return map<String,Object>`.

How do I define Setter & Getter method in Beans for this attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Use getter/setter that take/return Object, Jackson will by default determine the type from the json stream.

The only problem is that Jackson will deserialize to a list and not an array (you can however convert it to an array in the setter).

If you really want an array by default, you can have a look at Genson library http://code.google.com/p/genson/